# Traveling to Brazil & Argentina, passport expires in less than 3 months, will I have a problem entering?

Tags: passports, brazil, bulgarian-citizens

I have a flight to Brazil in 2 days and (due to personal negligence) I just realized my passport expires in less than 3 months.

My passport is Bulgarian. I don't need a visa for Brazil (up to 90 days). I'm planning to stay about a month.

On my government's website, it doesn't mention anything about validity requirements - only that the passport is valid at the time of entry.

After Brazil I was planning to go to Argentina (also visa free for 90 days). At that time my passport would be valid for only 1 month.

I am planning to return to my country of residence (Spain) about a week before the passport expires.

I also have an ID card (EU) that's valid for the next 8 years.

There's a Bulgarian consulate in the Brazilian city where I'm staying, I could also go there and try to get a new (emergency) passport.

I've been reading a lot about the 6-month-passport-validity rule, but there's no clear information for my case. Some sources say that Brazil and Argentina enforce it, other say they don't. Wondering if anyone has experience with a similar situation?

Answer (score 2):

Entry requirements can ofter be found on government websites that have travel advice.

The UK government website says for Brazil your passport must have at least 6 months validity.

> Your passport should be valid for a minimum period of 6 months from
>   the date of entry into Brazil.

https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/brazil/entry-requirements

For Argentina it says just the duration of your stay.

> Your passport should be valid for the proposed duration of your stay. No additional period of validity beyond this is required.

https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/argentina/entry-requirements

I know this is British travel advice but it will be valid for all passports that have the same visa requirements for these countries. British and Bulgarian citizens have the same entry requirements for both of these countries.

Comment: Thanks - I actually saw this. On my government's website it says the opposite (duration of stay for Brazil, 6 months for Argentina). I'm flying in less than 20 hours, so I'll just go there and see what happens I guess :)

Comment: Well let us know what happens, I guess it could come down to the discretion of the Immigration officer, and may just stamp you passport for the days you say you will be staying.